Include file with a path that is a variable (Flask/Jinja2)
Is there some way to make this work in flask (this is in a html template)?
{% include "posts/{{post}}" %}
I expected this to redirect to "/posts/(whatever the post var is - in this case 5)", however it actually redirects to "/post/{{post}}"

You're already inside {% %} tags, so you don't need {{ }}.  Try {% include "posts/" post %}

In Jinja2 {% include %} is used to render another template within the current template yet you seem to be passing it a url rather than the path to another template. It may help if you were to show us the entire surrounding line of html as well as your desired output.

@brandizzi Thanks, I couldn't find anything online, and this worked!

I believe one cannot use expansion with {{ }} inside a {% %} block. I would try to concatenate the path:
{% include "posts/" + post %}

